# Detect when CD drive was closed

Tags: c#

So I am making a little project for myself. I need to detect if the CD Drive was closed, and if it was, run a function.

Is this possible?

Comment: "if it was run a function".  Can you phrase that in English please?

Comment: You do know that not all CD drives even have trays at all, right?

Comment: @HansPassant: Think you might be being a LITTLE harsh over a missing comma. ;)

Comment: I have a suspicion that the optical drive notifies the OS that a disc has been inserted, not that the tray has been closed, but you could get all [WM_DEVICECHANGE messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363480%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and investigate further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need to define the function that will be opening the disk tray:

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "mciSendString")]
public static extern int mciSendStringA(string lpstrCommand, string lpstrReturnString, 
                            int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback);
```

To close(or check if the drive is closed) the disk drive you need to send two command strings .

```
mciSendStringA("open " + driveLetter + ": type CDaudio alias drive" + driveLetter, 
                 returnString, 0, 0);
mciSendStringA("set drive" + driveLetter + " door closed", returnString, 0, 0);
```

The function returns`0` if the command is successfully executed or else it returns an error code.So you can have a logic to check that.

You can check the [documentation of the function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  and also a useful [link](http://www.vcskicks.com/disk-drive.php) for more info

Answer (score 2):

Checkout following tutorial

[Detect CD-ROM Insertion](http://tutorials.csharp-online.net/index.php?title=Detect_CD-ROM_Insertion)

Comment: I saw that, but I want to detect if it was closed, not if a disk was inserted. Like literally they open it and then close it, and have the program detect that.

Answer (score 1):

As far i understand the question is you want to detect there is a disk in side the drive and running or maybe just one inserted. if so this snippet will help you

```
using System;
using System.Management; 

class Application
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery( "select * from win32_logicaldisk where drivetype=5" );
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);

        foreach( ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get() )
        {
          // If both properties are null I suppose there's no CD
             if( ( mo["volumename"] != null ) || ( mo["volumeserialnumber"] != null ) )
             {
                 Console.WriteLine( "CD is named: {0}", mo["volumename"] );
                 Console.WriteLine( "CD Serial Number: {0}", mo["volumeserialnumber"] );
             }
             else
             {
                 Console.WriteLine( "No CD in Unit" ); // Here you can make sure there is no disk.
             }
        }

        // Here to stop app from closing
        Console.WriteLine( "\nPress Return to exit." );
        Console.Read();
   }
}
```

[source](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/295010/How-to-Detect-CD-ROM-is-loaded-in-the-CD-ROM-drive